# исключить из первого массива данные которые совпадают со вторым

Tags: php, массивы

Здравствуйте ребята помогите с массивами мне нужно исключить из первого массива данные которые совпадают со вторым вот что мне нужно исключить по значению img как указано в переменной $result

```
$array=array(
array=(
"tag"=>"name",
"link"=>"site.com",
"img"=>"link.com/img.jpg",
"like"=>12
),array=(
"tag"=>"name",
"link"=>"site.com",
"img"=>"link.com/img2.jpg",
"like"=>12
)
)
$exclude=array('link.com/img1.jpg','link.com/img2.jpg','link.com/img3.jpg');

$result=array(array=("tag"=>"name","link"=>"site.com", "img"=>"link.com/img.jpg","like"=>12));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = array_filter(
    $array, 
    function($v) use ($exclude) { return !in_array($v['img'], $exclude); }
);
```